# retrieve a @Named managed bean from session scope

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee-6, cdi

i've a question about the new JEE6 CDI specification, in particular the use of @Inject in conjunction with `@Named` annotations that seems to have replaced the jsf specific `@ManagedBean` (for register resource) and `@ManagedProperty` (for injection) annotations.

Assuming you have a bean class "`User`" annotated `@ManagedBean @SessionScoped` and an object of this class is injected in any bean using `@ManagedProperty` then when this object is created and injected it is also put in session and i could access the session (for example in a filter) and retrieve object using:

```
User user = (User)((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("user");
```

So, if I try the same logic (in glassfish 3.1.2) using `@Named @SessionScoped` and then `@Inject` I can confirm that there is no such object of type `User` in session, but this is what i find in session:

```
attribute_name:  org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationIdGenerator    
attribute_value:  org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationIdGenerator@b374765 

attribute_name:  org.jboss.weld.context.ConversationContext.conversations            
attribute_value:   {}
```

where i'm doing wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

If you annotate a bean with `@SessionScoped`, you are basically binding its lifecycle to the HttpSession. This does not mean that the bean is physically injected into the session-object.

> Assuming you have a bean class "User" annotated @ManagedBean
>   @SessionScoped and an object of this class is injected in any bean
>   using @ManagedProperty then when this object is created and injected
>   it is also put in session and i could access the session (for example
>   in a filter) and retrieve object using:

Very important: don't mix JSF and CDI annotations. Make all beans you want to access from within a JSF template `@Named`, and use CDI's `@Inject` and `@...Scoped`, that's sufficient.

To answer your question:

```
@SessionScoped
public class User { ... }


@RequestScoped
public class SomeController { 

@Inject
User user

...
}
```

This will create `User` when the session starts and inject it into `SomeController` when `SomeController` is instantiated (with a new request, in this example).

Have a look at the [Weld documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html) to get a more complete start with that topic...